# Unexpected function expression prefer-arrow-callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I keep getting a `warning`:

> 181:30  warning  Unexpected function expression  prefer-arrow-callback
>
> ✖ 1 problem (0 errors, 1 warning)   0 errors and 1 warning potentially
> fixable with the `--fix` option.

It's specifically on this line: `snapshot.forEach(function(child)`:

**What's this warning for?**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.calculateTotalRating = functions.https.onRequest((data, response) => {

    const postId = data.postId;
    
    const totalUsersCtRef = admin.database().ref('/posts/' + postId + '/' + 'totalUsersCt');
    const postsRef = admin.database().ref('/posts/' + postId);

    var ratingsSum = 0.0;

    admin.database().ref('reviews').child(postId).once('value', snapshot => {

        if (snapshot.exists()) {

            snapshot.forEach(function(child) { // *** the warning is for this line ***

                ratingsSum += child().val()
            })
            .then(() => { 
            
                return postsRef.set({ "ratingsSum": ratingsSum})          
            })
            .then(() => { 
            
                return totalUsersCtRef.set(admin.database.ServerValue.increment(1));                
            }) 
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('ERROR - calculateTotalRating() Failed: ', error);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-arrow-callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [exactly what it sounds like](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-arrow-callback) - the linter is telling you to use an arrow function in the `forEach` callback instead of a `function`.

```
snapshot.forEach((child) => {
```

Comment: ahhh, ok thanks, I'm not native with Javascript. Let me try it now. I can't accept your answer for 12 minutes.

Comment: I changed it to this `snapshot.forEach((child) =>` and the same exact warning on the same exact line appeared again.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Maybe your linter is working on an old version of the file? Try restarting your IDE

Comment: You was correct, I had to close terminal, open it, and start over. Thanks for the help!!!